# How to get selected features properties dynamically in Open Layers 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers-3

I have two types in map which is Point and Polygon. Each type has own properties like id, doorNo, name etc. My feature list created by ;

```
var features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(geojsonObject, {
    featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
});
```

If I call features by index I can get properties using get('property_name') function. For example;

```
features[0].getGeometry().getType() == "Point" // check this feature is Point or not
$doorNo = features[$index].get("doorNo");//this is also works
```

But at the same time I have a selectInteraction on my map. And when I select a feature I want to get all these same properties via button on click  event. To do that I write this;

```
$('#btnSelected').on('click', function () {
        if (selectInteraction) {
            // use the features Collection to detect when a feature is selected,
            // the collection will emit the add event
            var selectedFeatures = selectInteraction.getFeatures();
            console.log("Length: " + selectedFeatures.getLength());// this is works
            console.log("Coordinates: " + selectedFeatures[0].getGeometry().getCoordinates());//THIS GAVES ME ERROR
        }else
            console.log('there is no selected feature.');
    });
```

So, in click event I want to write to console all feature property but even if selectedFeatures.length gaves me correct number I can't get any property at all.
Where am I going wrong?

[image]

Note: In the Map, blue one is selected point. And first two uncaught error is irrelevant for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getFeatures` method returns an [`ol.Collection`](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Collection.html), not an Array.

`ol.Collection`s do not support retrieving its items using the JS bracket notation. Instead of `selectedFeatures[0]` do `selectedFeatures.item(0)`.

Comment: You can use getArray() method of ol.Collection to get the underlaying array too : var selectedFeatures = selectInteraction.getFeatures().getArray();